# Predicate builder SELECT all alternative

Tags: c#, .net, predicate, linqkit

I am creating filter for app and I have two approaches to same window, first approach is when I am passing **code** and getting all records with it, second when I need to get all records when **code** is Null or Empty. Searched a lot for solution but did not found any

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.New<Foo>();

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(requestModel.code))
{
    predicate = predicate.And(x => x.code == requestModel.code);
}

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(requestModel.code))
{
    //here I want to get all records from table
}

return await context.Foo
  .AsExpandable()
  .Where(predicate)
  .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

Comment: don't use a predicate then, what's the problem?

Comment: Something like `predicate = predicate.Or(x => true);` ?

Comment: @stuartd Thank you, it worked, I did't even thought that about this way

Answer (score 0):

You can start by passing a true value when you use PredicateBuilder:

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.New<Foo>(true);
```